# Android: ExtendedFloatingActionButton .shirk() does not work

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design, material-components-android

I'm using `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton` and trying to shrink that button by calling `.shrink()` but nothing is happening.

This is my button xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout ... >

...

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/exploring_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-24dp"
    android:text="Start Exploring"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_walking" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My fragment's code:

```
    Log.d(TAG, "shrinking start")
    binding.exploringBtn.shrink(object :
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton.OnChangedCallback() {
        override fun onShrunken(extendedFab: ExtendedFloatingActionButton?) {
            super.onShrunken(extendedFab)
            Log.d(TAG, "onShrunken: ")
        }

        override fun onExtended(extendedFab: ExtendedFloatingActionButton?) {
            super.onExtended(extendedFab)
            Log.d(TAG, "onExtended: ")
        }
    })
    Log.d(TAG, "shrinking end")
```

My logcat output (demonstrating that after I execute the `.shrink()` method twice but nothing happens):

```
2021-07-13 20:28:41.453 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: listenForPathData: isExploring: true
2021-07-13 20:28:41.454 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: shrinking start
2021-07-13 20:28:41.465 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: shrinking end
2021-07-13 20:28:42.089 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: checkIfNeedToRequestPermissions: need to request permissions: false
2021-07-13 20:28:53.917 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: listenForPathData: isExploring: true
2021-07-13 20:28:53.918 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: shrinking start
2021-07-13 20:28:53.922 17098-17098/uk.co.explorer D/kesD: shrinking end
```

My gradle material dependency looks like:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Comment: Have you verified that you can interact with the FAB in other ways? For example, changing the visibility? If not it might be an issue with your binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I simply wrapped the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` in a `LinearLayout`. Not optimal, but fixes the issue. I believe the problem may have been related to a bottom sheet layout I had in the same screen. The code is now as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/extend_btn_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/exploring_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Start Exploring"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_walking" />

</LinearLayout>
```